# Trying Test Scripts spec.ts fails because expect(like return) executes before create response came and shows undefined in console

Tags: typescript, automated-tests, angular6, karma-jasmine, ionic4

I am using angular 6 and parse database and I have implemented a test script for creating method.

Implemented create function in sample page component and service is implemented in the test service file. when I run ionic serve command and save using angular it created properly 
   but when I implemented test script for creating function it creates data but spec fails because expect executes before create response came and shows undefined in the console in the spec file.

### Here Implemented the sample Test script File sample.page.spec.ts:

```
      it('units page create function spec', () => {
        component.formData.optionName="testpiece";
        component.formData.optionDesc="testdescription";

        component.save();   

        fixture.detectChanges();  
        console.log("component.designationObject",component.designationObject);

        expect(component.designationObject).toEqual("Units Created Successfully"); 
      })
```

---

Fails because expect(like return)  executes before create response came and shows undefined in the console.

Answer (score 0):

How does your create/save method exactly look like? For this answer, I assume that you are working with promises. If so, you have to call your async code as follows:

```
 it('units page create function spec', (done) => {
        component.formData.optionName="testpiece";
        component.formData.optionDesc="testdescription";

        component.save().then(result => {
          fixture.detectChanges();  
          console.log("component.designationObject",component.designationObject);

          expect(component.designationObject).toEqual("Units CreatedSuccessfully");
          done();
        });   

      })
```

This will trigger the expect call after your promise completes.
Note the call of the `done` callback after expect.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I am not using promises in component page, in save method after callback it is save in designation variable & designation variable is used for comparison in test cases.but before callback expect is calling in spec file.

          save() {

         var saveobj = {
                "optionName": this.formData.optionName,
                "optionDesc": this.formData.optionDesc,       
              }      

                  this.testService.save(saveobj, (callback) => {

                this.designationObject = callback.status;    
  
              });      }

Comment: Ok I see, you are just calling the testservice.save method.So why not testing the testService.save() method and in your component test mock the test service? It's unit testing you don't have to test functions twice.